# php heredoc syntax question

Tags: php

Trying to output the following 5 but not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$other='What are you like?';
 $content['my_name']=4;

$str=<<<JT
    here is some info. $other Do 
    you like the number {$content['my_name']+1} ? 
JT;

 echo $str . '<br />';
```

Comment: I don't think you can do operations in HEREDOC blocks. You would have to prepare the variable beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pekka correctly stated:

```
$str=<<<JT
    here is some info. $other Do 
    you like the number {$content['my_name']+1} ? 
JT;
```

is invalid - only variables are parsed in the heredoc..

```
$content['my_name'] += 1;
$str=<<<JT
    here is some info. $other Do 
    you like the number {$content['my_name']} ? 
JT;
```